# Service Intent must be explicit - Google Analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics, gradle, google-play-services, android-5.0-lollipop

Possibly duplicate of [Android 5.0 (L) Service Intent must be explicit 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26530565/android-5-0-l-service-intent-must-be-explicit) with minor differences

Im getting this error in Lollipop - Nexus 5

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.analytics.service.START (has extras) }
        at android.app.ContextImpl.validateServiceIntent(ContextImpl.java:1674)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1773)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1751)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:538)
        at com.google.analytics.tracking.android.AnalyticsGmsCoreClient.connect(AnalyticsGmsCoreClient.java:82)
        at com.google.analytics.tracking.android.GAServiceProxy.connectToService(GAServiceProxy.java:330)
        at com.google.analytics.tracking.android.GAServiceProxy.createService(GAServiceProxy.java:210)
        at com.google.analytics.tracking.android.GAThread.init(GAThread.java:85)
        at com.google.analytics.tracking.android.GAThread.run(GAThread.java:352)
```

I had my project using maven with google analytics v3 and play services 4.3.23 and everything work fine even in lollipop nexus 5.

After i migrate to gradle, i kept analytics v3 and updated play services to 6.1.71, don't know if this could be the problem

More stacktrace

```
2-04 14:23:42.331  13618-13759/com.xxxxxx.mypackage V/GAV3﹕ Thread[GAThread,5,main]: connecting to Analytics service
12-04 14:23:42.337  13618-13759/com.xxxxxx.mypackage W/System.err﹕ java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.analytics.service.START (has extras) }
12-04 14:23:42.337  13618-13759/com.xxxxxx.mypackage W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ContextImpl.validateServiceIntent(ContextImpl.java:1674)
12-04 14:23:42.337  13618-13759/com.xxxxxx.mypackage W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1773)
12-04 14:23:42.338  13618-13759/com.xxxxxx.mypackage W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1751)
12-04 14:23:42.338  13618-13759/com.xxxxxx.mypackage W/System.err﹕ at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:538)
12-04 14:23:42.338  13618-13759/com.xxxxxx.mypackage W/System.err﹕ at com.google.analytics.tracking.android.AnalyticsGmsCoreClient.connect(AnalyticsGmsCoreClient.java:82)
12-04 14:23:42.338  13618-13759/com.xxxxxx.mypackage W/System.err﹕ at com.google.analytics.tracking.android.GAServiceProxy.connectToService(GAServiceProxy.java:330)
12-04 14:23:42.338  13618-13759/com.xxxxxx.mypackage W/System.err﹕ at com.google.analytics.tracking.android.GAServiceProxy.createService(GAServiceProxy.java:210)
12-04 14:23:42.338  13618-13759/com.xxxxxx.mypackage W/System.err﹕ at com.google.analytics.tracking.android.GAThread.init(GAThread.java:85)
12-04 14:23:42.338  13618-13759/com.xxxxxx.mypackage W/System.err﹕ at com.google.analytics.tracking.android.GAThread.run(GAThread.java:352)
12-04 14:23:42.342  13618-13759/com.xxxxxx.mypackage W/FlurryAgent﹕ Error logged: uncaught
12-04 14:23:42.342  13618-13759/com.xxxxxx.mypackage W/FlurryAgent﹕ Trying to end session
12-04 14:23:42.346  13618-13759/com.xxxxxx.mypackage W/FlurryAgent﹕ Ending session
12-04 14:23:42.350  13618-13759/com.xxxxxx.mypackage V/GAV3﹕ Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Tracking Exception: IllegalArgumentException (@ContextImpl:validateServiceIntent:1674) {GAThread}
12-04 14:23:42.351  13618-13759/com.xxxxxx.mypackage V/GAV3﹕ Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Dispatch call queued. Dispatch will run once initialization is complete.
12-04 14:23:42.351  13618-13759/com.xxxxxx.mypackage V/GAV3﹕ Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Passing exception to original handler.
12-04 14:23:42.351  13618-13759/com.xxxxxx.mypackage E/ACRA﹕ ACRA caught a IllegalArgumentException exception for com.xxxxxx.mypackage. Building report.
12-04 14:23:42.565  13618-13759/com.xxxxxx.mypackage I/ACRA﹕ READ_LOGS granted! ACRA can include LogCat and DropBox data.
12-04 14:23:42.603  13618-13759/com.xxxxxx.mypackage D/ACRA﹕ Retrieving logcat output...
12-04 14:23:42.629  13618-13759/com.xxxxxx.mypackage D/ACRA﹕ Writing crash report file 1417710222000.stacktrace.
12-04 14:23:42.643  13618-13759/com.xxxxxx.mypackage D/ACRA﹕ About to start ReportSenderWorker from #handleException
12-04 14:23:42.645  13618-14173/com.xxxxxx.mypackage D/ACRA﹕ Mark all pending reports as approved.
12-04 14:23:42.645  13618-14173/com.xxxxxx.mypackage D/ACRA﹕ Looking for error files in /data/data/com.xxxxxx.mypackage/files
12-04 14:23:42.646  13618-14174/com.xxxxxx.mypackage D/ACRA﹕ Waiting for Toast + worker...
12-04 14:23:42.649  13618-14173/com.xxxxxx.mypackage D/ACRA﹕ #checkAndSendReports - start
12-04 14:23:42.649  13618-14173/com.xxxxxx.mypackage D/ACRA﹕ Looking for error files in /data/data/com.xxxxxx.mypackage/files
12-04 14:23:42.650  13618-14173/com.xxxxxx.mypackage I/ACRA﹕ Sending file 1417710222000-approved.stacktrace
12-04 14:23:42.661  13618-14173/com.xxxxxx.mypackage D/ACRA﹕ Sending report 180cde9c-d8e3-4d00-b677-185630e6c44b
12-04 14:23:42.661  13618-14173/com.xxxxxx.mypackage D/ACRA﹕ Connect to https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/formResponse?formkey=dE04R1o0VjJDM29QXaQ2ZTVjSVNzdGc6MQ&ifq
12-04 14:23:42.708  13618-14173/com.xxxxxx.mypackage D/ACRA﹕ Sending request to https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/formResponse?formkey=dE04R1o0VjJDM29QXaQ2ZTVjSVNzdGc6MQ&ifq
12-04 14:23:42.991  13618-13618/com.xxxxxx.mypackage I/INFO﹕ Address from preferences ->null
12-04 14:23:42.991  13618-13618/com.xxxxxx.mypackage I/INFO﹕ Address from preferences ->null
12-04 14:23:42.991  13618-13618/com.xxxxxx.mypackage I/INFO﹕ Address from preferences ->null
12-04 14:23:42.991  13618-13618/com.xxxxxx.mypackage I/INFO﹕ Address from preferences ->null
12-04 14:23:42.991  13618-13618/com.xxxxxx.mypackage I/INFO﹕ Address from preferences ->null
12-04 14:23:42.991  13618-13618/com.xxxxxx.mypackage I/INFO﹕ Address from preferences ->null
12-04 14:23:43.000  13618-13618/com.xxxxxx.mypackage I/INFO﹕ *****************************
12-04 14:23:43.000  13618-13618/com.xxxxxx.mypackage I/INFO﹕ Cancel move camera
12-04 14:23:43.000  13618-13618/com.xxxxxx.mypackage I/INFO﹕ *****************************
12-04 14:23:43.059  13618-13618/com.xxxxxx.mypackage V/GCMBroadcastReceiver﹕ onReceive: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION
12-04 14:23:43.059  13618-13618/com.xxxxxx.mypackage V/GCMBroadcastReceiver﹕ GCM IntentService class: com.xxxxxx.mypackage.GCMIntentService
12-04 14:23:43.061  13618-13618/com.xxxxxx.mypackage V/GCMBaseIntentService﹕ Acquiring wakelock
12-04 14:23:43.066  13618-13618/com.xxxxxx.mypackage V/GCMBaseIntentService﹕ Intent service name: GCMIntentService-670358886800-1
12-04 14:23:43.066  13618-13618/com.xxxxxx.mypackage E/GCMBaseIntentService﹕ [GCMIntentService] start
12-04 14:23:43.069  13618-14192/com.xxxxxx.mypackage E/GCMRegistrar﹕ internal error: retry receiver class not set yet
12-04 14:23:43.070  13618-13618/com.xxxxxx.mypackage V/GCMBroadcastReceiver﹕ onReceive: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION
12-04 14:23:43.070  13618-14192/com.xxxxxx.mypackage V/GCMRegistrar﹕ Registering receiver
12-04 14:23:43.070  13618-13618/com.xxxxxx.mypackage V/GCMBroadcastReceiver﹕ GCM IntentService class: com.xxxxxx.mypackage.GCMIntentService
12-04 14:23:43.070  13618-13618/com.xxxxxx.mypackage V/GCMBaseIntentService﹕ Acquiring wakelock
12-04 14:23:43.073  13618-14192/com.xxxxxx.mypackage D/GCMBaseIntentService﹕ handleRegistration: registrationId = null, error = null, unregistered = com.xxxxxx.mypackage
12-04 14:23:43.074  13618-14192/com.xxxxxx.mypackage D/GCMRegistrar﹕ resetting backoff for com.xxxxxx.mypackage
12-04 14:23:43.074  13618-14192/com.xxxxxx.mypackage V/GCMRegistrar﹕ Saving regId on app version 25
12-04 14:23:43.089  13618-14192/com.xxxxxx.mypackage V/GCMIntentService onUnregistered﹕ [ 12-04 14:23:43.090 13618:14192 V/GCMBaseIntentService ]
    Releasing wakelock
12-04 14:23:43.092  13618-14192/com.xxxxxx.mypackage D/GCMBaseIntentService﹕ handleRegistration: registrationId = APA91bHiOw6h7JU9dvLc1Qqw04GXQkrlbV-4LZIQfO6e8uIEGaFSsVNqsdmTi53PXZVEARzI6XLxK3rXXM3OrUm8wIRC0jmgB2yXrrVRoTkSvwQXtPSywJR2AJkcs_2a39KwvLxnyN97JLdP8hVVLtSElBCGYLNMyDIlXYWC01i7Th4OyVA1FOM, error = null, unregistered = null
12-04 14:23:43.092  13618-14192/com.xxxxxx.mypackage D/GCMRegistrar﹕ resetting backoff for com.xxxxxx.mypackage
12-04 14:23:43.095  13618-14192/com.xxxxxx.mypackage V/GCMRegistrar﹕ Saving regId on app version 25
12-04 14:23:43.116  13618-14192/com.xxxxxx.mypackage V/GCMIntentService onRegistered﹕ APA91bHiOw6h7JU9dvLc1Qqw04GXQkrlbV-4LZIQfO6e8uIEGaFSsVNqsdmTi53PXZVEARzI6XLxK3rXXM3OrUm8wIRC0jmgB2yXrrVRoTkSvwQXtPSywJR2AJkcs_2a39KwvLxnyN97JLdP8hVVLtSElBCGYLNMyDIlXYWC01i7Th4OyVA1FOM
12-04 14:23:43.116  13618-14192/com.xxxxxx.mypackage V/GCMBaseIntentService﹕ Releasing wakelock
12-04 14:23:43.660  13618-13634/com.xxxxxx.mypackage I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 57034(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 53(2MB) LOS objects, 13% free, 35MB/41MB, paused 8.499ms total 70.673ms
12-04 14:23:43.872  13618-14173/com.xxxxxx.mypackage W/ResponseProcessCookies﹕ Invalid cookie header: "Set-Cookie: NID=67=rrqRFddFUdEd6qmmRaW7u3wCSFSDlVoFobX4NqYeDntag4sOwuzwAeWjh6q3tsENizFX-5igAcBPOUj0M_QXkQKGPfKeCzpDD5-oXrveoj8D1flwIx1TCB5v8i0F6CHR;Domain=.google.com;Path=/;Expires=Fri, 05-Jun-2015 16:24:18 GMT;HttpOnly". Unable to parse expires attribute: Fri
12-04 14:23:43.872  13618-14173/com.xxxxxx.mypackage E/ACRA﹕ Failed to send crash report for 1417710222000-approved.stacktrace
    org.acra.sender.ReportSenderException: Error while sending report to Google Form.
            at org.acra.sender.GoogleFormSender.send(GoogleFormSender.java:88)
            at org.acra.SendWorker.sendCrashReport(SendWorker.java:178)
            at org.acra.SendWorker.checkAndSendReports(SendWorker.java:141)
            at org.acra.SendWorker.run(SendWorker.java:77)
     Caused by: java.io.IOException: Host returned error code 404
            at org.acra.util.HttpRequest.sendPost(HttpRequest.java:139)
            at org.acra.sender.GoogleFormSender.send(GoogleFormSender.java:85)
            at org.acra.SendWorker.sendCrashReport(SendWorker.java:178)
            at org.acra.SendWorker.checkAndSendReports(SendWorker.java:141)
            at org.acra.SendWorker.run(SendWorker.java:77)
12-04 14:23:43.873  13618-14173/com.xxxxxx.mypackage D/ACRA﹕ #checkAndSendReports - finish
12-04 14:23:43.950  13618-14174/com.xxxxxx.mypackage D/ACRA﹕ Wait for Toast + worker ended. Kill Application ? true
12-04 14:23:43.951  13618-14174/com.xxxxxx.mypackage E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: GAThread
    Process: com.xxxxxx.mypackage, PID: 13618
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.analytics.service.START (has extras) }
            at android.app.ContextImpl.validateServiceIntent(ContextImpl.java:1674)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1773)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1751)
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:538)
            at com.google.analytics.tracking.android.AnalyticsGmsCoreClient.connect(AnalyticsGmsCoreClient.java:82)
            at com.google.analytics.tracking.android.GAServiceProxy.connectToService(GAServiceProxy.java:330)
            at com.google.analytics.tracking.android.GAServiceProxy.createService(GAServiceProxy.java:210)
            at com.google.analytics.tracking.android.GAThread.init(GAThread.java:85)
            at com.google.analytics.tracking.android.GAThread.run(GAThread.java:352)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google In-App billing, IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit, after upgrading to Android L Dev Preview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24480069/google-in-app-billing-illegalargumentexception-service-intent-must-be-explicit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lollipop enforces a security restriction that you cannot call `startService()`, `stopService()` or `bindService()` with implicit `Intent`s.  In order for this to work on Lollipop, update your code to specify the `ComponentName` in the `Intent`.

Comment: Well im not calling any services method(or at least i don't know if im calling) could be some lib im using? Roboguice 2 or GCM maybe? And thanks for your answer!

Comment: Can you provide a longer backtrace from logcat?  It may be the way in which you are interfacing with analytics.

Comment: Also, you mentioned switching to gradle for you build: how did you integrate play services and analytics into your build?

Comment: I updated the question with more logs, to integrate play services and analytics i only added the dependencies `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.71'
    compile 'com.google.analytics:services:3.0'`

Comment: This looks as though you have another library using Google forms which may be tapping into analytics and that's causing a problem; but, it's pretty difficult to say for sure.  Analytics 3.0 is considered deprecated, but I've not seen any info on it failing to work at all.

Comment: I think the problem was using analytics v3 with google play services 6.1.71, i discovered that google analytics v4 is integrated with play services so i think this could be the problem, ill implement analytics v4 now

Comment: "update your code to specify the ComponentName in the Intent" : what does that mean ? May you be more specific ? Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Update the GA to version 4. It will work.