# Migrating from google analytics V2 to V4

Tags: android, google-analytics

I'm a new Android developer, I recently encountered a problem on updating my app to Android 5.0. Same issue here: [Android 5.0 (L) Service Intent must be explicit in Google analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26530565/android-5-0-l-service-intent-must-be-explicit)

According to that solution, I'm gonna updating from google analytics V2 to V4 (google play service). But the painful part is seems for every page, I need to change the tracking code. There are around 30 pages(activities and fragments) in my app, this is really not scalable, and easy to make regression bugs.

I was wondering is there any better way to do the migration? Thanks.

Comment: I have posted a simple way to implement GA(V4). Migration is not a easy task. Something you need to do manually. While you are using this code you must update the google play lib in your project. Try this following link. It may help you.

Google Analytics - NetworkOnMainThreadException on send in AsyncTask

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android 5.0 (L) Service Intent must be explicit in Google analytics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26530565/android-5-0-l-service-intent-must-be-explicit-in-google-analytics)

Answer (score 1):

I created a small class, it's have same siganture of v2 in the body it's call a v4 methods, you can check it at my 
[gist](https://gist.github.com/ameen-sarsour/8180ab52469191c4f202)