# app crashes when start connection with baidu push service

Tags: android, exception, push-notification

I am using baidu push service in my android app. It is working fine except in lollipop version. When i run the app in device with lollipop version it crashes.i am getting the below crash log.

```
    02-03 11:55:39.772: E/AndroidRuntime(17430): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.sample.myapp: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit: Intent { act=com.baidu.android.pushservice.action.PUSH_SERVICE (has extras) }
02-03 11:55:39.772: E/AndroidRuntime(17430):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4521)
02-03 11:55:39.772: E/AndroidRuntime(17430):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:144)
02-03 11:55:39.772: E/AndroidRuntime(17430):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1339)
02-03 11:55:39.772: E/AndroidRuntime(17430):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-03 11:55:39.772: E/AndroidRuntime(17430):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
02-03 11:55:39.772: E/AndroidRuntime(17430):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
02-03 11:55:39.772: E/AndroidRuntime(17430):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-03 11:55:39.772: E/AndroidRuntime(17430):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
02-03 11:55:39.772: E/AndroidRuntime(17430):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
02-03 11:55:39.772: E/AndroidRuntime(17430):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
02-03 11:55:39.772: E/AndroidRuntime(17430): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit: Intent { act=com.baidu.android.pushservice.action.PUSH_SERVICE (has extras) }
02-03 11:55:39.772: E/AndroidRuntime(17430):    at android.app.ContextImpl.validateServiceIntent(ContextImpl.java:1674)
02-03 11:55:39.772: E/AndroidRuntime(17430):    at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1703)
02-03 11:55:39.772: E/AndroidRuntime(17430):    at android.app.ContextImpl.startService(ContextImpl.java:1687)
02-03 11:55:39.772: E/AndroidRuntime(17430):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:515)
02-03 11:55:39.772: E/AndroidRuntime(17430):    at com.baidu.android.pushservice.util.q.i(Unknown Source)
02-03 11:55:39.772: E/AndroidRuntime(17430):    at com.baidu.android.pushservice.util.q.l(Unknown Source)
02-03 11:55:39.772: E/AndroidRuntime(17430):    at com.baidu.android.pushservice.internal.PushManager.startWork(Unknown Source)
02-03 11:55:39.772: E/AndroidRuntime(17430):    at com.baidu.android.pushservice.apiproxy.BridgePushManager.startWork(Unknown Source)
02-03 11:55:39.772: E/AndroidRuntime(17430):    at com.baidu.android.pushservice.PushManager$40.run(Unknown Source)
02-03 11:55:39.772: E/AndroidRuntime(17430):    at com.baidu.android.pushservice.LoadExecutor.excuteMethod(Unknown Source)
02-03 11:55:39.772: E/AndroidRuntime(17430):    at com.baidu.android.pushservice.PushManager.startWork(Unknown Source)
02-03 11:55:39.772: E/AndroidRuntime(17430):    at com.sample.myapp.onCreate(HUSApp.java:62)
02-03 11:55:39.772: E/AndroidRuntime(17430):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1011)
02-03 11:55:39.772: E/AndroidRuntime(17430):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4518)
02-03 11:55:39.772: E/AndroidRuntime(17430):    ... 9 more
```

And given below is the code which throws exception

```
PushManager
                .startWork(getApplicationContext(),
                        PushConstants.LOGIN_TYPE_API_KEY, BaiduUtils
                                .getMetaValue(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "api_key"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Android 5, bindService() must always be called with an explicit intents. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28151732/3060087

You should change the intent that starts the PushService to be explicit (mentioning the package and service name) instead of implicit (mentioning just the action as an intent filter).

Another option is to use Android v19 or less as the target.

Comment: The code to connect with service is written in the library jar file.So not able to edit it. Tried with target SDK as API 19. It has some issues when run the app in lollipop version os.

Comment: What problems are you seeing? BTW, I hope you are using the latest Baidu library - otherwise, you could ask them to fix this issue in the next release.

Comment: not getting push notifications properly,and onBind is calling infinitely

Comment: These may be due to problems in your code and not the library

Comment: it is fixed in 4.4 release

Answer (score -1):

old Baidu-Frontia-Full-Debug-2.0.6.jar update to pushservice-5.6.0.30.jar
The system encounter this error,you can delete Frontia relevant class,end this error.
http://developer.baidu.com/announcement/89