# Android App crashes on Lollipop

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-5.0-lollipop

hi I am using google license checker on my app it works on API 19 and below but crashes on lollipop. I saw the code that has to be add to my license check code but I don't know where to put this code or what should I edit. here is my code

log:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit: Intent { act=com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService }
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit: Intent { act=com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService }
at android.app.ContextImpl.validateServiceIntent(ContextImpl.java:1674)
at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1773)
at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1751)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:538)
at com.google.android.vending.licensing.LicenseChecker.checkAccess(LicenseChecker.java:150)
at appinventor.ai_drsalmanshah165.Clinical_Examination.Splash.doCheck(Splash.java:103)
at appinventor.ai_drsalmanshah165.Clinical_Examination.Splash.onCreate(Splash.java:51)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
... 10 more
```

Java code:

```
public class Splash extends Activity {

MyLicenseCheckerCallback mLicenseCheckerCallback;
LicenseChecker mChecker;
byte[] SALT = new byte[] {
         my salt no.             };
     //Handler mHandler;
     String BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY="MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAoxvDF3HGQtrRch14wCPN6nAxasak8X4shJM6bCumNS+6xRXTnRZOSyAvHNa1145KlE/i1sy/";
     Context mContext;
     IBinder serviceBinder;
     String deviceId;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    mLicenseCheckerCallback = new MyLicenseCheckerCallback();
    deviceId = Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    // Construct the LicenseChecker with a policy.
    mChecker = new LicenseChecker(
        this, (Policy) new ServerManagedPolicy(Splash.this, new AESObfuscator(SALT, getPackageName(), deviceId)),
        BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY);
    doCheck();


}

private class MyLicenseCheckerCallback implements LicenseCheckerCallback {


    @Override
    public void allow(int reason) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         if (isFinishing()) {
                // Don't update UI if Activity is finishing.
                return;
            }

        // Toast.makeText(Splash.this, "License Verified", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         Intent intent=new Intent(Splash.this,Home.class);
         startActivity(intent);
         finish();

            // Should allow user access.
            // so do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void dontAllow(int reason) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         if (isFinishing()) {
                // Don't update UI if Activity is finishing.
                return;
            }
       //  Toast.makeText(Splash.this, "License Verification Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         createDialog();
    }

    @Override
    public void applicationError(int errorCode) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mChecker.onDestroy();
}

private void doCheck() {
       // mCheckLicenseButton.setEnabled(false);
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
      ///  mStatusText.setText(R.string.checking_license);
        mChecker.checkAccess(mLicenseCheckerCallback);
}

public void createDialog(){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("PIRACY WARNING");
    builder.setMessage("This application is not licensed. Please purchase it from Android Market.  If you received this message in error, please contact Support.");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Buy Now", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(
                "http://market.android.com/details?id=" + getPackageName()));
            startActivity(marketIntent);
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Quit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            finish();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
}
}
```

and here  is the other code which I got that this can solve my problem. but don't know where to put it.

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(
     new String(Base64.decode("Y29tLmFuZHJvaWQudmVuZGluZy5saWNlbnNpbmcuSUxpY2Vuc2luZ1NlcnZpY2U=")));
     serviceIntent.setPackage("com.android.vending");

     boolean bindResult = mContext
             .bindService(
               serviceIntent,
               this, // ServiceConnection.
               Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

Comment: Are you targeting api 21 in the gradle?

Comment: <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

Comment: Firstly post the log ,secondly I think implicit intents are no longer supported http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0-changes.html

Comment: i am facing the same issue.

Comment: By the way, target+minSDKVersions are defined within the app's build.gradle file- NOT within the manifest file any more. Editing the sdk versions in the manifest does nothing. Just for double checking~

Comment: ok. but now I am facing the lollipop crash problem. solve this

Comment: @MDragon00 Based on his 'Eclipse' tag your statement is incorrect.  If the user is continuing to use Eclipse then they likely have not adopted gradle and the manifest would be the correct location for those defines

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android 5.0 (L) Service Intent must be explicit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26530565/android-5-0-l-service-intent-must-be-explicit)

Comment: Possible duplicate of already solved issue?
http://stackoverflow.com/a/27804282/2102748

Comment: Read the very first line: `Service Intent must be explicit`  If you don't know what that means, Google it.

Answer (score 61):

Waiting for an official solution, the current solution consists in **patching Google's LicenseChecker class**

```
com.google.android.vending.licensing.LicenseChecker.checkAccess(LicenseChecker.java:150)
```

like this:

```
new String(
-    Base64.decode("Y29tLmFuZHJvaWQudmVuZGluZy5saWNlbnNpbmcuSUxpY2Vuc2luZ1NlcnZpY2U="))),
+    Base64.decode("Y29tLmFuZHJvaWQudmVuZGluZy5saWNlbnNpbmcuSUxpY2Vuc2luZ1NlcnZpY2U=")))
+    .setPackage("com.android.vending"), // this fix the 'IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit'
     this, // ServiceConnection.
```

Adding package name with statement **setPackage("com.android.vending")** makes the Intent explicit, i.e., 'safe' (as requested by Android Lollipop )

**Note:**

Please pay attention as after modifying LicenseChecker class you must change the min sdk version from 3 to 4 (thanks [russellhoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/828551/russellhoff))

**Source:**

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78505#c19

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to find the solution for hours. The place, which should be fixed is easy to find with Ctrl-click on "mChecker.checkAccess(mLicenseCheckerCallback);" - Ctrl-click on checkAccess and you will get there in Android Studio. I think this answer should be accepted as a correct one.

Comment: The correct solution would be, if google upgraded their libraries and migrate them to gradle as well..

Comment: Working for me. Please pay attention as after modifying LicenseChecker class you must change the min sdk version from 3 to 4 (@Pascal you should warn users in your message)

Comment: @Billda http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2010/09/securing-android-lvl-applications.html

Comment: @Billda I have pre-migrated LVL and expansion pack libraries to gradle and I have incorporated fixes like this https://github.com/coltsoftware/ExpansionAPKsAndroidStudio

Comment: Getting lvl working in android studio should NOT require all these manual hacks....get it together Google.

Comment: Please also see this issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61680. Emulators with API levels 19-22 seem to have a problem that makes the license checker crash (`unfortunately, license checker has stopped`). Using e.g. API level 23 for the emulator solves that.