# Service must be explicit when opening Activity having map: Android lollipop(5.0)

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, explicit-intent

I have google map displayed in a FragmentActitvity which implements 
And to open this activity I am start an intent from another activity(let's say Activity A) on click of a button.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MapActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

And my MapActivity is like this:

```
public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity implements GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    private LocationClient locationClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
    if (googleMap == null) {
        googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        // check if map is created successfully or not
        if (googleMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    locationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
    locationClient.connect();
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();

    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(5 * 1000);
    mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(0.1f);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000);
}
}
```

The MapActivity has other other implementation method of interfaces as well.
But when I click on button to open MapActivity I get the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit: Intent { act=com.google.android.location.internal.GoogleLocationManagerService.START }
```

I searched on google and I found I need to create an explicit intent. But I am not sure how to do that in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade your Android SDK Build-tools with Android SDK Manager. Choose last version of the build-tools. And then in your build.gradle

```
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
```

The best way is to upgrade on new GoogleApiClient, your new MapActivity should be like this

```
public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {
    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            // check if map is created successfully or not
            if (googleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationRequest.setInterval(5 * 1000);
        locationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(0.1f);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000);

        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // handle new location
    }
}
```

And you should use last play-services. In your build.gradle

```
dependencies {

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.5.0'
}
```

Comment: Downgrading is not really an option.

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski i'm agree. Edited

Comment: I refered this:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26530565/android-5-0-l-service-intent-must-be-explicit 
link where i found that i need to to setPackage() before calling bindService(), but i dont know where this change needs to be done in my code.