# Android request to another service - explicit vs implicit intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to make a request to another service (another app), but getting exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Service Intent must be explicit: Intent { act=com.myApp.DoAction }
```

I did some readings and still confused:
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26530565/android-5-0-l-service-intent-must-be-explicit-in-google-analytics/28151732#28151732), it's written: `Since Android 5.0 (Lollipop) bindService() must always be called with an explicit intent.` 
[Here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#Types), it's written: `Implicit intents do not name a specific component, but instead declare a general action to perform, which allows a component from another app to handle it`

What will be the right intent? What will be the right example?
I am doing:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setAction("com.anotherApp.MyService");
// binding to remote service
bindService(intent, AddServiceConnection, Service.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

Many many thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this
`Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);`

line of code says that intent action is implicit. It declares intent with abstract SEND action. try removing `Intent.ACTION_SEND`

Answer (score 0):

After trying some tutorials: 
Intent is implicit and [this nice example shows how to deal with it](https://www.sitepoint.com/aidl-for-sharing-functionality-between-android-apps/)

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.anotherapp.MyService");
intent.setPackage("com.anotherapp");
bindService(intent, AddServiceConnection, Service.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```